# udev rule not working

Tags: linux, bash, mount, udev

I am trying to write a udev rule for USB drive plugin. I want to first mount it to `/media` and then run the script at `/usr/local/bin/script.sh`. When I insert the USB, it doesn't even mount the device with this rule. However, If I manually type the part in RUN into terminal, It mounts and executes script.

The rule file says:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", RUN+="/bin/mount -t auto /dev/%k /media/ && /usr/local/bin/script.sh"
```

Is this the right way to execute two commands in RUN section of the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/bin/mount` doesn't take `&&` as an argument. If you want a shell chain to be executed then you must pass it to a shell.

```
RUN+="/bin/sh -c '...'"
```

Comment: Did you mean something like `RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'xdg-open /mnt/Passport1T && /bin/mount /dev/usbdevices/Passport1T /mnt/Passport1T'"`? It doesn't seem to work for me. Nothing special in the syslog to debug. Any idea?

Comment: Other than stop trying to run user programs in a system context?